# How to define child's child in css without mentioning the 1st child?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have html like this:

```
 <div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            Some more detailed code....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to know how to refer to "C" using "A" in CSS, without defining "B" because the class content varies and it would be difficult to use it, so I cannot define it. Also the "A" must be included, because the "C" occurs in other parts of web and I cannot change it there.

Thank you

Comment: `.A .C { ... }` or `.A div .C { ... }` ?

Comment: Yes, this seemed to work, thank you for your help!

Comment: no problem. I'll move it to an answer if you like. I didn't think other people would answer with the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that would be great, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
.a div .c {
  ...
}
```

Or even this will work, but will included even direct children:

```
.a .c {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.A .C{
   attribute goes here  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the middle class to target a child. You can just target with `.A .C { ... }`, or `.A div .C { ... }` if you know `.B` will be a `div` and you want to limit it that way.

You can also use the child combinator selector if you want to limit depth. Like `.A > div > .C` would target your example's exact depth.